# constraints are not applied to UITextField inside Cell of UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode8

Trying to set the constraint for my **UITextfield** inside a cell of a **tableview** to be like in the image below

[image]

my constraints are:

[image]

> When running the app on my simulator the uitextfield appear on the top left

[image]

i know my question does not have enough details but what i am facing wrong with constraints to be as i want, forget to mention that i try to close XCode and reopen it restart my mackbook all these situations give me the same result; i feel that there is a bug in my XCODE

> XCODE Version 10.1 (10B61)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not giving width to the text filed so that's why it's not look like that text field.

just insert few more word's then you will see your text field width will increase.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see any bottom or height constraint. There is only top, leading and trailing. Could you check if you added any bottom constraint?
Other ideas:
What about the constraints of the table view cell or table view itself? do you add any? Did you check in the xcode debug inspector, the constraints of the tableview ,cell and textfield? Check if there are any warning in the debug inspector.